# Cannot pass shell variable into AWK and have script run to completion

Tags: awk

I am attempting to pass command line arguments into an awk script, but upon doing so the command line becomes unresponsive and I have to kill the program.

```
var1=$3
var2=$4
awk -v x="$var1" -f awk_script
```

I know the variable is seen by the awk script because it is printed by it, but it gets hung up and doesn't allow me to enter the next command. I have seen similar posts that say this is how it is done but I know the problem lies in these lines because excluding these three lines allows the script to run to completion. Any thoughts?

Comment: Post a complete, (but small/tiny) example with small sample input, expected output from that input, and the **code** in `awk_script` . Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not hang - it's waiting for input.

To prove this, type some characters into console after start.

You forgot to provide the file name of the file which shall be processed. E.g. if file to process is named `FILE_TO_PROCESS`:

```
var1=$3
var2=$4
awk -v x="$var1" -f awk_script FILE_TO_PROCESS
```

Alternatetively, you may pipe contents into stdin of the script. E.g.:

```
var1=$3
var2=$4
awk -v x="$var1" -f awk_script <FILE_TO_PROCESS
```

or:

```
var1=$3
var2=$4
cat <FILE_TO_PROCESS | awk -v x="$var1" -f awk_script
```

---

By testing this in my bash, I made an interesting (for me surprising) observation:

An awk script *without* any pattern terminates immediately (without waiting for input):

```
$ cat >no-scan.awk <<'EOF'
> BEGIN { print "x: "x }
> EOF

$ awk -v x="Hello" -f no-scan.awk
x: Hello

$
```

An awk script with at least one pattern waits for input:

```
$ cat >scan.awk <<'EOF'
> BEGIN { print "x: "x }
> $0 { print NR": "$0 }
> EOF

$ awk -v x="Hello" -f scan.awk
x: Hello
Some input typed with keyboard
1: Some input typed with keyboard
more
2: more
more
3: more

$
```

(I finished input with **Ctrl**+**D**.)

I'm not sure whether this is the default behavior of awk. May be, I should mention that I did this with gawk in cygwin64 of my Windows 10.

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.
```

I tried to find some reference about this but I couldn't. Excerpt from manual on [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

> *Gawk* executes AWK programs in the following order. First, all variable assignments specified via the **-v** option are performed. Next, gawk compiles the program into an internal form. Then, gawk executes the code in the **BEGIN block**(s) (if any), and then proceeds to read each file named in the **ARGV** array. If there are no files named on the command line, gawk reads the standard input.

...

> For each record in the input, *gawk* tests to see if it matches any pattern in the AWK program. For each pattern that the record matches, the associated *action* is executed. The patterns are tested in the order they occur in the program.
>
> Finally, after all the input is exhausted, gawk executes the code in the **END block**(s) (if any).

IMHO, this does not say explicitly that the absence of patterns skips processing of input though it makes sense to me.

By googling this topic I found other examples. It seems that even the default action (without pattern) forces processing of input as well as the occurrence of `getline` (even if it is in the **BEGIN** rule).

Comment: Do you know if i can simply import these values to my awk script and then run that awk script later in the same bash script?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question. Please, consider, that 1. an awk script may provided as command line argument 2. the provided script (on command line) may contain constant text as well as bash variables which are resolved before the script is executed in awk. Thus, in a bash script, you may build parts of the awk script out of bash variables. ("bash script" includes direct input on bash command prompt.)

Comment: Example: `VAR=Hello ; echo "Hello World" | awk "/$VAR/ { print \"Pattern found\" }"` prints `Pattern found`. After resolving the variables, the bash calls awk actually with this script: `/Hello/ { print "Pattern found" }`. You can make this visible with `set -x` which enables bash debugging.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I figured it out. I appreciate your thoroughness